# LINQ version of SQL's LIKE statement

Tags: sql, linq

I'm new at LINQ, searching the net for LINQ samples that mimic SQL's LIKE statement doesn't satisfy myself.

What I want is producing the same query result as this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE column_1 LIKE '__0%'
```

I want to query from table_1 where column_1's third character is '0'

Is there equivalent statement in LINQ

:D thank you

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [SqlMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx) class. It's part of System.Data.Linq (a.k.a. LINQ to SQL).

```
from item in db.Table1
where SqlMethods.Like(item.Column1, "__0%")
select item;
```

Comment: if it is not obvoius by Steven's comments, this does not work with LINQ to Entity. You will need to use Andrey's approach.

Comment: Although the `SqlMethods.Like` allows direct translation to the SQL LIKE statement, prefer the use of the `string` methods (such as StartsWith and Contains) where possible, because this results in code that is more maintainable.

Answer (score 12):

Likes are produced by following methods: `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains`. Try to play with them.

Comment: He needs only the third character to be zero, so I guess he should look at `Substring` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I can't test it right now):

```
from t in table_1
where t.column_1[2] == '0'
select t;
```

Comment: @Marcelo: Probably because the code doesn't work as the underscore has a special meaning when used with `like`, but not when used with `StartsWith`.

Comment: Doesn't this check if the entry starts with "__0" instead of if the third character is a "0"?

Comment: `_` means any character in a `LIKE` statement, whereas it has no special meaning to `StartsWith`.

Comment: D'oh! Those underscores get me every time!

Answer (score 0):

In your exact case (assuming column_1 is a string):

```
from t in table_1
where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.column_1) && t.column_1.Length >= 3 && t.column_1[2] == '0'
select t;
```

Of course, you have the entire .NET library at your disposals and could use some sophisticated pattern matching API (like regular expressions) if you need a more general solution:

```
var regex = new Regex("..0.*");
var qry = from t in table_1
          where regex.Match(t.column_1).Success
          select t;
```

Comment: Regular expression won't work for L2SQL, which I believe the OP is using (although it's not 100% clear)

Comment: oh, didn't know that. But regular string matching techniques works, right?